# declar function in javascript to use it many times

Tags: javascript, html

I have been declared a function witch show infowindow on map

```
   function showArrays(event) {

     var string = 'hello world'   

      infoWindow.setContent(string);

      infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.close();

      });


  infoWindow.open(map);}
```

the problem that when i declare it like this :

```
var string = 'hello world';

function showArrays(event,string) {


  infoWindow.setContent(string);

  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();

  });
```

`infoWindow.open(map);}`

it does'nt work !!!

i want to declaret like that to used many times

i call it like that `showArrays(event,string)`
and the infowindow i declare it above .

`thanks for helping

Comment: what error you are getting in console please try to make fiddle to anyone can figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Don’t use the same variable name as one of your parameters then. Also, showing us how you _call_ the function is quite important.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle and also can you let us know from where you are calling the function.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you passing `string` as the second argument when you call it? The parameter variable shadows the global variable.

Comment: `var string = 'hello world';

function showArrays(event,string) {


  infoWindow.setContent(string);

  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();

  });infoWindow.open(map);}
` try this you are missing close function braces is it the issue or it's just a typo?

Comment: its typo @Curiousdev bro

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having, is that you are only declaring it just fine, however you are not calling, it so you will never get inside the function.

also: second declaration is missing end curly bracket so would result in error.

```
var arr = ['hello', 'world'];

function showArrays(event, str) {
   infoWindow.setContent(str);
   infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
       infoWindow.close();
   });
   infoWindow.open(map);
}

for(index in arr){
    var item = arr[i];
    showArrays(someEvent, item);//this is where you call it 
}
```

Lastly, you `infoWindow` object is not declared anywhere, so this will fail also.

I think you are moving too fast in trying to learn JavaScript, go back a few steps and learn the basics, before you continue to such advanced level of it.

Comment: no working bro
and didn't get me i want to call this function many times with many strings .thanks

Comment: See changed function.

Comment: not working @Val because i'm calling is function in area.addListener
so when i click on this area it will show me information but i have many ares and each one with spesifice text